# Change the table row color based on what is displayed from the Enum property on a view. ASP.Net MVC

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, enums

I'm trying to change the `table row` color based on what is displayed in the `table` on my `index` page of my `delivery`.

I have 3 `statuses` for `delivery` which I've hard-coded using `enum` in the `model`. Now based on the respective status I want the table row to change color.

So for example, if my `status` is equal to `Dispatched`, change the `table row` color to `.success` which my bootstrap takes as green.

This is what I have tried so far, but it's not working. Does any one have any ideas for a fix?

**Delivery Index View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string style = item.Status.Equals("Dispatched") ? "success" : null;

    <tr class="@style">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Driver.First_Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Driver.Last_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dispatched_Date) at
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dispatched_Time)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delivered_Date) -
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delivered_Time)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delayed_Date) -
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delayed_Time)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("View Delivery", "Details", new { id = item.DeliveryID })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete Delivery", "Delete", new { id = item.DeliveryID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**Model:**

```
public enum Status
{
   Dispatched, Delayed, Delivered
}
public class Delivery
{

    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Driver")]
    public int DriverID { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
```

Comment: either answer below should work.. your problem is most likely that you're comparing the Status enum to string instead of the enum Dispatched   `item.Status.Equals(Status.Dispatched)`

Comment: `item.Status.Equals(Status.Dispatched)`doesn't appear to work. It brings up an error saying that  System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.Status doesn't have a definition for dispatched.

Comment: guess it's looking in the wrong namespace.. add your namespace

Comment: Could you perhaps give me an example of what it would look like? I'm not entirely sure, since I'm still new to Asp.Net Mvc.

Comment: `string style = item.Status == MyProjectName.Models.Status.Dispatched ? "success" : string.Empty;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr class="@(item.Status == WebApplication15.Models.Status.Dispatched ? "success" : String.Empty)">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Driver.First_Name)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Driver.Last_Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dispatched_Date) at
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dispatched_Time)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delivered_Date) -
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delivered_Time)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delayed_Date) -
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Delayed_Time)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("View Delivery", "Details", new { id = item.DeliveryID })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete Delivery", "Delete", new { id = item.DeliveryID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And here's the status enum

```
namespace WebApplication15.Models
{
    public enum Status
    {
        Dispatched, Delayed, Delivered
    }
}
```

Notice how the full namespace and enum name is used in the view.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just one issue with `Status.Dispatched` . It brings up an error saying that System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.Status doesn't have a definition for dispatched?

Comment: Youre referencing System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.Status. You need to reference your Status enum instead!

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm pretty new to Asp.Net so I'm not that familiar with how to go about it.

Comment: Sorry this was partly my fault. In my answer I accidentally put in the System.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.Status namespace so you will need to remove this. I've updated the answer which shows the namespace removed.

Comment: It seems to now have a problem with `Status.Dispatched`. It says that status doesn't exist in the current context. Could I have perhaps missed something? Should I have declared on the page.

Comment: You need the namespace of the Status enum. I'll update my answer to show you what I mean. 2 secs...

Answer (score 2):

```
@functions {
     public string CalculateStyle(Status status){
        return status == Status.Dispatched ? "success" : string.Empty;
     }
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr class="@CalculateStyle(item.Status)">

    </tr>
}
```

Comment: what is `@function`? is it like `@helper`?

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/173/the-difference-between-helpers-and-functions-in-webmatrix

Comment: ah.. `@functions { }`

Answer (score 0):

The first answer kinda gave me a direction, Thanks.

I had a table with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
```

among other columns and I wanted to color the `Status` column only.

if its **Accepted**, I wanted to be `success` color else `danger` color

so here is what I did

```
<td class="text-@(item.Status == "Accepted" ? "success" : "danger")">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
</td>
```

hope it helps or at least gives a direction

Its never too late to add some value, I provided mine